# Fibonacci identity

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

The Fibonacci numbers, given by $f_0 = 1$, $f_1 = 1$ and $f_n = f_{n-1} + f_{n-2}$, for $n \geq 2$  have many interesting properties. Many of these interesting properties can be easily proven combinatorially by interpreting the Fibonacci numbers as the number of ways,to tile a $1\times n$ board with squares ($1\times 1$ tiles) and dominoes ($1\times 2$ tiles). This interpretation has been generalized to interpret recurrence relations with nonnegative
integer coecients and initial conditions. Specially, 
$$g_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{k} a_ig_{n-i}$$
with the $a_i$s non-negative integers can be interpreted as the number of ways to tile a board of length $n$ with tiles of length $1$ through $k$, where tiles of length $i$ are given one of $a_i$ colors, and the rst tile is given a certain number of phases depending on the $a_i$ the initial conditions, and the length. **Can you generalize this?**

Comment: Thank you for editing. there are still some minor mistakes there in my typing. f_n = f_(n-1) + f_(n-2) and after sigma, a_ig_(n-i) is required. If possible, edit. Thank you.

Comment: *Generalize*... but in which direction, for which purpose?

Answer (score 4):

I recall much work along such lines, which is confirmed by a quick web search, e.g.

[The Combinatorialization of Linear Recurrences](http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_18/PDF/v18i2p12.pdf)

[Linear Recurrences Through Tilings and Markov Chains](http://www.math.hmc.edu/~su/papers.dir/tilingchain.pdf)

[Classical q-Series Identities via Tilings](http://www.math.psu.edu/dlittle/pubs/TilingsIII.pdf)

[A Tiling Approach to Eight Identities of Rogers](http://www.math.psu.edu/dlittle/pubs/RRTilings.pdf)

Comment: good. The second one is little better than others.